# Cut selected data from 10GB CSV file with two delimiters

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I've got a 10GB CSV file which I'm trying to cut select output from.
At the moment I've got the following, but due to its size it's consuming (way) too many resources, so I'm looking to optimize it.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=data.txt
FILEPATH=/home/user/

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        echo "No search parameter specified. Specify one when running this."
fi

echo "Searching $FILEPATH/$FILE for $1.. this may take a while."
echo ""

while IFS= read -r LINE;
        do
                # Grep for $1 and cut select columns
                grep $1 | cut -d"," -f7,9,15,16,19,22,23,24
        done
```

A sample line of the input file looks as follows:

> RESULTS: key=value1,error=0,command=SetOperator|SOURCE:
>   file=/home/user/logs/current,start_date=20130128,

What I'd like to do is to search the file for any value and have it return (a cut version of) results from every line on which a result is found.
For example, searching for '20130128' should return:

> SetOperator,value1,20130128,

Which means that I'll need to handle both command and equals as a delimiter.

I've looked around on SO (i.e., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197500/performance-issue-with-parsing-large-log-files-5gb-using-awk-grep-sed)) and spent some Google-fu and while I find it is generally accepted that 'read' is slow and not optimized for large files such as these; I'm not finding many alternatives.

What would you recommend me to use?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you simply do `grep "$1" "$FILEPATH/$FILE"  | cut -d"," -f7,9,15,16,19,22,23,24` ? No need to loop over the lines in bash, unless I misunderstand you ...

Comment: I could, but due to the size of the file it takes > 10 minutes to find anything at all. Ideally I'd like to bring this down to < 1 minute.

Comment: Your bottleneck is CPU or I/O? And which process is the one causing the bottleneck, grep or cut?

Comment: I don't see where you use the LINE variable declared for your read. The only thing that will be faster than greping a file is to split it up and perform multiple greps, but of course when splitting you have to read the file amd write it (which takes even longer). Or you can look at a system that's designed for parallel processing like hadoop, but that will only help if you to do this more than once. Finally, you if this is a go-forward project, consider changing the process to create smaller files that can be parallel processed without having to preprocess. Good luck. (Rethink your problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your command as written:

```
while IFS= read -r LINE;
        do
                # Grep for $1 and cut select columns
                grep $1 | cut -d"," -f7,9,15,16,19,22,23,24
        done
```

would never terminate because you aren't running grep ON anything, neither a file nor a pipe.

Instead of that loop with grep plus a pipe plus cut, try this:

```
awk -v re="$1" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $0~re{print $7,$9,$15,$16,$19,$22,$23,$24}' "${FILEPATH}/${FILE}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a 10GB file to test on, but the grep man page show two option's that may help:

> --line-buffered
> Use line buffering on output. This can cause a performance penalty.
>
> --mmap
> If possible, use the mmap(2) system call to read input, instead of the default read(2) system call. In some situations,
> --mmap yields
> better performance. However, --mmap can cause undefined behavior
> (including core dumps) if an input file shrinks while grep is
> operating, or if an I/O error occurs.

The line buffering option would make the whole command run slower however you would start getting results quicker, mmap can be weird.

using those options then looping would be uneccessary as below:

```
grep --mmap "pattern" file | cut -d"," -f7,9,15,16,19,22,23,24
```

or

```
grep --line-buffered "pattern" file | cut -d"," -f7,9,15,16,19,22,23,24
```